# react using store class for Ajax calls

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a store using typescript something like this:

```
class GetDataStore {

    public getData() {
        const url = "http://localhost:50774/api/Data";
        fetch(url).then(res => {
            if (res.ok) {
                return res.json();
            } else {
                throw new Error("Something went wrong in retrieving data");
            }
        }).then(resData => { return resData })
            .catch(error => { console.log(error) });
    }
}

export default GetDataStore;
```

I am trying to instantiate an instance of this store as :

```
import { GetDataStore } from"../../stores/GetDataStore";
..
..
export class View extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>> {

    private store = new GetDataStore();

    public componentWillMount() {
        const data = store.getData();
    }
}
```

But I am getting an error:

> _GetDataStore.GetDataStore is not a constructor at new View

What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exporting the `GetDataStore` class as a default export but importing it as a named export.
You can remove the brackets from around the import:

```
import GetDataStore from"../../stores/GetDataStore";
```

RTFM should work here as well: [export guide from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)

Answer (score 1):

Your `import` statement is a named import, however you are using a `default` export.

**Solution 1 (using `default` export):**

Try replacing:

`import { GetDataStore } from"../../stores/GetDataStore";`

with:

`import GetDataStore from "../../stores/GetDataStore";`

**Solution 2 (using named export):**

Remove:

`export default GetDataStore;`

And replace:

`class GetDataStore {`

with:

`export class GetDataStore {`